# uWSGI suitable for Rails production app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uwsgi

our system administrator just proposed to move a rails app of ours from nginx/passenger to nginx/uwsgi, but uwsgi seems to be little used by the ruby-community: I was unable to find any benchmark comparisons for uwsgi and other rack servers or other experiences of users.

Can anyone confirm using uWSGI for a RoR app is a good (or bad) idea? Please also share your experience with this server.

Thanks,

Niels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met the same issue recently. I did some investigation and successfully deployed a Rails web site onto uwsgi.

http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki states that the support for Ruby is "Stable". So I think it is ready for production.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How is it working up to now? Have you had any issues? The thing is, I was a bit reluctant to use it, as there seems no real community of users (that I could find), even though the uWSGI site stated that it is stable and production-ready.

Comment: I haven't met any issue. everything works great. but I have to confess that my site doesn't have many visitors. Here is the link if you are interested: http://en.cvanalyze.com/

Comment: Could you guys share your configs? Sorta bummed out by the lack of docs/community involvement. Anyway here are mine (work in progress): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3298a806e9b0ae04896d4cc6489f8db1

Comment: Same here, I ended up never using it, just because I couln't find any proof that it was production ready.